# java recurrsion with ArrayList not working

Tags: java, recursion

I am doing recursion for a given phone number and print all the possible string representation of the number. The problem is in loop `for (int j=0;j<ops;j++) {` the size of the "perm" ArrayList keep increasing in every iteration. I want to get fixed pattern and add new number e.g perm = 11 and call recursion with tperm=110,111,112.

```
import java.util.*;

public class phoneNum {

    public static void getSt ( List<Integer>list , List<Integer> perm ) {

        Integer len = list.size();
        Integer len1 = perm.size();
        Integer ops = 0;

        if (len == len1) {

            for(int k=0;k<len;k++) {
                System.out.print(" " + list.get(k));
            }
            for(int k=0;k<len;k++) {
                System.out.print(" " + perm.get(k));
            }
            System.out.print("====");
            System.out.print(getPattrn(list,perm));
            System.out.println("\n");

        } else {
            for (int i=0; i<len1+1; i++) {
                if(list.get(i) == 7 || list.get(i) == 9) {
                    ops = 4;
                } else {
                    ops = 3;
                }
                for (int j=0;j<ops;j++) {
                    List<Integer> tperm = new ArrayList<Integer>(perm);
                    tperm.add(i,j);
                    System.out.println("Size=" +  tperm.size() + " ---" + perm.size());
                    getSt(list,tperm);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Whats up with your getPattern Method?

Answer (score 0):

You can add tperm.remove(i) at the end of inner for loop.

Comment: It worked. The problem was with my loops. I did not need loop with i.